# What is the least privilege required for getting serviceaccounts including cluster-admin bound accounts?

Tags: go, kubernetes, minikube, client-go

I have a k8s cluster in minikube, configured a service account `admin-user` with the `cluster-admin` role, and am configuring the ServiceAccount below to use in my own application. Everything is applied in the same `namespace` and my spec is using the `me` serviceAccountName.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: me

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: myRole
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["serviceaccounts, secrets"]
    verbs: ["get"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: myRoleBinding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: me
    namespace: namespace
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: myRole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

My application uses the `rest.InClusterConfig`.

When executing `client.CoreV1().ServiceAccounts("namespace").Get(ctx, "admin-user", meta.GetOptions{})` I get this error:

`serviceaccounts "admin-user" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:namespace:me" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "namespace"`

When I bind the `me` ServiceAccount to the default `view` ClusterRole instead of `myRole`, my client call then works. From what I can tell, I am granting the same privileges necessary for serviceaccounts in `myRole` compared to `view`.

It seems I am not granting the correct privileges but I can't figure out what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in `resources: ["serviceaccounts, secrets"]`.

Should be `resources: ["serviceaccounts", "secrets"]`.